# Desktop media query overriding all screen sizes

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

I am implementing mobile first approach to media queries. I have set min-width media queries at 37.5em and 50em for tablet and desktops.

I wish for the project section to display as a column for mobile, and row for desktop. My desktop media query seems to over ride everything else.

HTML:

```
<section id="projects">

<h2>Projects</h2>

<div id="projects_container">

<figure class="hvr-float-shadow">
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="ImagePlaceholder.png">
    <figcaption>Random Quote <br> Generator</figcaption>
</figure>


 </section>
```

Mobile first CSS:

```
#projects{
padding-top: 5rem;
padding-bottom: 15rem;
background-color: #FFFAFA;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;

}


 #projects_container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;


}

 figure{
 display: block; 
 position: relative; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 width: 75%;
 }

 figure img {
width: 100%;
}

 figcaption { 
 position: absolute; 
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
 color: white; 
 padding: 10px 20px; 
 width: 100%;


 opacity: 0;
 bottom: 0; 
 top: -30%;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
-o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
opacity: 1;
top: 0;
}
```

Offending desktop media query:

```
@media (min-width: 50em) {
#projects_container {
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 145%;
    align-items: center;

}
#unhide-text {
display: inline;
}

figure{
display: block; 
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden; 
width: 25%;
}


.contact-container{

    flex-direction: row;
  }

}
```

My understanding is that media query should only apply if the criteria is met.

What am I missing?

https://sandbagger.github.io/MyPortfolio/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, media query applies correct at 50em, so we need to have a _working code snippet_ reproducing the issue you speak about.

Comment: Maybe 50em is too small.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `em` use `px`. And check the breakpoints for `tablets` and `mobiles`.

Comment: Changing to `px` won't solve anything, and _mobile first_ mean there is no breaking point for `mobiles`